# Override/Inset new alt tag from <figcaption> tag

Tags: jquery, html

I have a piece of jQuery, see below, that wraps my images in a href tag so they can be used in a lightbox.

I need to adjust what appears in the alt tag as well, and it needs to be generated from whatever the user puts in the caption box in ckeditor (which generates a figcaption tag under each image). I need to be able to insert that data into the empty alt="" and be able to override if there is anything currently in the alt tag.

The html that is being output at the moment is:

```
<figure class="image">
    <a data-imagelightbox="f" href="/ckfinder/userfiles/files/Screenshot_South-Downs-Lines-RSC_51_23330-1_22091_10-00-48.jpg">
        <img width="1600" height="900" src="/ckfinder/userfiles/files/Screenshot_South-Downs-Lines-RSC_51_23330-1_22091_10-00-48.jpg" alt="Caption 1"></img>
    </a>
    <figcaption>
        Caption
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

The current script I have is as follows:

```
$('#article-copy img').each( function() {
    var $img = $(this),
        alt = $img.next('figcaption').text(),
        href = $img.attr('src');
    $img.wrap('<a href="' + href + '" data-imagelightbox="f"></a>');
});
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: Is this the HTML before or after the function runs?

Comment: The html is what is generated after the jquery runs, which only currently wraps the image in the href, but doesn't alter the alt tag currently, which is what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to change the `alt` attribute of the image. Then this should work:

```
$('#article-copy img').each( function() {
    var $img = $(this),
        alt = $img.next('figcaption').text(),
        href = $img.attr('src');
    $img.attr('alt', alt );
    $img.wrap('<a href="' + href + '" data-imagelightbox="f"></a>');
});
```